# Rigify widgets generating in wrong position and won't rotate

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, rigify

I am having issues with the rig i generated through rigify. When I hit "generate rig" a rig is created with the "palm" widget turned vertical instead of horizontal.

I also cannot rotate any of the widgets in pose mode. The widget highlighted in blue will not move or rotate. The same thing happens with other blue and green widgets in the rig.

[image]

The file is located here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ihXQGdsvz6mLsUTXckzLgcRS05c_jw_D/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That file location (Google Drive) is locked and inaccesible.

Comment: appologies! i've unlocked it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ihXQGdsvz6mLsUTXckzLgcRS05c_jw_D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The link seems to be dead now. Upload again and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in the duplicate topic here: [Rigify generated rig, hand IK controller has unexpected rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198822/rigify-generated-rig-hand-ik-controller-has-unexpected-rotation/198840#198840)

The generated rig tries to correct the roll automatically by default, but this can be overwritten by selecting each upper_arm bone and in Bone Properties > Rigify Type > Rotation Axis selecting the rotation axis manually. If you have copied the roll orientations from the human metarig template, then this should be Z manual for the arms. This causes the hand IK control to be correctly oriented when generating the rig.

[image]