# Rigify generated rig, hand IK controller has unexpected rotation

Tags: rigging, armature, add-on, bones, rigify

I am having the same exact issue as described here: 
 
[Rigify widgets generating in wrong position and won't rotate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194518/rigify-widgets-generating-in-wrong-position-and-wont-rotate). I would comment but do not have enough reputation. 

A three-fingered character with mis-rotation of the hand IK control. See the attached .blend file. I believe I have setup the metarig with the proper rolls, and changing the roll of the hand or palm bones in the metarig has no affect on the outcome in the generated rig. I believe I have also assigned the correct rig types to the first palm bone as well as each of the fingers. All other controllers/bones seem to generate correctly. I cannot seem to set roll manually in the generated rig either. Is there a workaround? 
 
[image] 
 
[image: The metarig with bone axes shown (orientation was mimicked from the template human metarig):]

[image: The generated rig with odd rotation of hand IK paddle. Looks to be the same rotation as in the referenced topic linked above]

[image: Another view of the issue]

Answer (score 4):

Solved with the help of CGDive! https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/25308/cgdive

The generated rig tries to correct the roll automatically by default, but this can be overwritten by selecting each *upper_arm* bone and in *Bone Properties* > *Rigify Type* > *Rotation Axis* selecting the rotation axis manually. If you have copied the roll orientations from the human metarig template, then this should be *Z manual* for the arms. This causes the hand IK control to be correctly oriented when generating the rig.

[image]

Comment: I am new to blender and have encountered this very issue. Thanks for the solution. I was however unable to find the Rigify Type menu for the longest time. You must be in Pose mode in order to access the menu. (Using blender 2.91)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone reach this page but mcurt09 answer didn't solved your problem, try adding an extra step and editing the hand rotation in edit mode before generate the control rig again. That's what solved it for me.